# I dont want two blues when mouse is over the TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

Here is the XAML codes.

I dont want two blues when mouse is over the TabItem.

I dont want two blues when mouse is over the TabItem.

I dont want two blues when mouse is over the TabItem.

I dont want two blues when mouse is over the TabItem.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Height="200" Width="400">

<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.15"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <TabControl Background="Pink">
        <TabItem Background="Yellow" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Customer" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Background="Yellow" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Customer" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Address" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Question:

[image]

So, I dont want two blues when mouse is over the TabItem.

Comment: Try putting name on a new line...instead of two controls. Or a `LineBreak`.. `<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Customer<LineBreak/>Name </TextBlock>`

Comment: My bad. This works `<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="Customer&#10;Name"></TextBlock>`... You need to set the `TextAlignment` of the `Text` and then include `&#10;` in between where you need a break.

Comment: What do you mean, works fine here. What framework are you targeting? If using < 4.0 it wont work... so you must be targeting an older framework?

Comment: Go to your project properties and check the framework you are using, if it is not > 4.0 it wont work. If you ***target*** 4.0 or above it will work...

Comment: Not sure at this point, I created a new project targeting 4.0 and it works just fine...

Comment: You are missing namespaces in your window... Please make sure all of these are there ` xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`

Comment: By default those are add when creating a new `Window`, they must have been removed. Also did you remove the `StackPanel`'s they are not needed.

Comment: With your update, you are not even using the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to change that is to edit the `TabItem` template, right click the `TabItem` from vs designer *EditTemplate > Edit a copy*, then look for a `LinearGradientBrush` with the key `TabItem.MouseOver.Background`, either change it to a `SolidColorBrush` with your color (and keep the same key):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Background" Color="Blue"/>
```

or update the `GradiantStop` points to use the same color:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Yes edit the template then change or remove the `LinearGradientBrush` that creates two shades of blue

Comment: Click ok, a new style will appear in the `Window.Resources` with the name "TabItemStyle1", and will be applied to the TabItem Control

Comment: This answer is senseless and will not benefit anyone. The issue is because the OP is stacking items, he doesn't need to do this. One block is fine for what he needs to do, I would have addressed that first...

Comment: @Codexer My answer addresses the issue itself which looks to me like a pure styling thing, the gradient will always be there even with one `Textblock` the only difference is that it won't be visible, changing the `GradiantBrush` to a Solid one looks like a better solution to me :))

Comment: No, just apply the new style to every Tab you want it to look like that

Comment: `Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}"` in your tabitem declaration. There's something else going on, I can't replicate this issue. As mentioned, I created a fresh new project dropped your code in, made changes as I suggested and it works fine.